# URL Rewrite Outbound Rule fails

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, reverse, outbound

I have two outbound rules that append ICSearch in front of the match. The following works-

```
<rule name="RewriteString"  preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
<match filterByTags="None" pattern="/Backflow/index\?handler=" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="ICSearch{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteString2"  preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
<match filterByTags="None" pattern="/Plumbing/index\?handler=" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="ICSearch{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

I would like to make it more generic and create a regex that will match regardless of the directory.

I have tried

```
<rule name="RewriteString2"  preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
<match filterByTags="None" pattern="(*.)\?handler=" ignoreCase="true" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="ICSearch{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

but it does not rewrite the values. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules You might dig deeper with FRT.

Comment: please correct your patter and use (.*). could you share what is your exact requirement by using some example